# makefile for two c programs

Tags: c, makefile

I have two c programs which I compile with gcc like this:

```
gcc prog1.c -o prog1
gcc prog2.c -o prog2
```

What would be the simplest makefile I could make for these so that when I type make, they both compile?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
all: prog1 prog2

prog1: prog1.c
    gcc prog1.c -o prog1

prog2: prog2.c
    gcc prog2.c -o prog2
```

The first target in a makefile (in this case, `all`) is the default, which runs when you use `make`. By convention, the first target is named `default` or `all`.

Note: be sure to insert actual tabulation chars before `gcc` command or `make` won't like the syntax.

Comment: What if I'm getting this when I type make: makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: the answer doesn't show the necessary <TAB> char before gcc

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Exactly. I don't know how to write them properly using SO editor.

Comment: This looks very verbose!

Answer (score 2):

I think simplest is to just use implicit  rules:

```
all: prog1 prog2
```